# Is dressing up for sex allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, sex

Is the woman allowed to wear Leather/PVC/latex trousers or catsuits to look sexy for her husband?

Are a couple allowed to visit a sex shop together?

When I say leather/PVC/Latex I mean what women in american films wear to look seductive such as dominatrix.

Answer (score 14):

> Is the woman allowed to wear Leather/PVC/latex trousers or catsuits to
>   look sexy for her husband?

Yes, she is allowed to wear such cloths.

> Are a couple allowed to visit a sex shop together?

In my opinion (also by some scholars) No. Because in Islam, we are not allowed to see Awra of other men or women. and these sex shops have all sorts of nudity (like nude pictures etc) present there. so you should not visit them.

And Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 9):

If a husband and wife can be naked, and have sex, with each other [Surah al-Muminun 23:5-6], then surely they can do other things together?

The verses of Hijab of a woman do not apply in front of her husband.

There is no ayah or sahih hadith that forbids a woman to wear provocative clothing for her husband.  In fact, she will probably be rewarded, Allaho alim.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But, the meaning of the ayats 23:5,6 does not mean that they can be naked. [Is it so?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/is-it-allowed-to-be-naked-during-sex)

Comment: These ayahs do not forbid it either, so by default it is allowed. For further guidance you may want to refer to this: http://islamqa.info/en/45514