# Is a married couple allowed to be naked during sex?

Tags: nikah, sex, husband-wife

I heard in a bayan (sermon) that the married couples should not be fully naked (without any clothes) even during sex.

[This answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12493/532) states that the ayats [23:5-6](http://quran.com/23/5-6) reveals that the couples can be naked.

Do these verses mean like that?

Is it allowed in Islam to be naked during sex?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from an Islamic point of view, almost all scholars agree that couple can be fully naked during sex.

Also, you have to understand that if you cannot even get naked during sex, then you do not enjoy it fully. And the purpose of sex is to fulfill the sexual desires of each other in every possible way. That's why Allah says in the Quran:

> "Your wives are as a tilth unto you; so approach your tilth when or
>   how ye will; but do some good act for your souls beforehand; and fear
>   Allah. And know that ye are to meet Him (in the Hereafter), and give
>   (these) good tidings to those who believe." (Al-Quran 2:223)

And the wisdom behind this verse is that the purpose of sex is to develop intimacy and fully release your sexual stress, so that you feel no need for it for some time.

My 3rd point is that everything is permitted in Islam, Unless it is Explicitly prohibited. But as there is Nothing related to prohibition of this act, so its fine to be naked during sex.

It's my personal advice that don't try to put any un-necessary restrictions during sexual acts. The more restrictions you put, more difficult it will get for both of you to enjoy the sex. The end result would be that none of you will get the proper pleasure.

For a detailed scholarly view, please refer to: http://islamqa.info/en/45514

And Allah knows best.

Comment: an additional argument to support that that it is allowed to be naked during sex, from quran 2:187 :

... They are clothing for you and you are clothing for them ...

Comment: Is there any evidence that Rasulullah(Sa) and any of his wife became naked? Rather Ayesha(Ra) said, I never saw Rasullah(Sa)'s private part and Rasullah(Sa) also never saw mine!

Comment: @manetsus https://sunnah.com/urn/1262410 https://sunnah.com/urn/1256610 - "Grade : Da'if (Darussalam)", "(Da'if)"

Comment: @manetsus an other weak argument to support disallowedness of nakedness is story of adam an hawa from quran near 7:20, "... But Satan whispered to them to make apparent to them that which was concealed from them of their private parts. ..."

Answer (score -2):

If I recall correctly, there is hadith(from [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1262400), if I remember) about criticizing "do not conduct intercourse like a naked donkeys"?

More knowledgeable brothers may further comment on it.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/urn/1262400

Comment: "Grade : Da'if (Darussalam)"